# Retaining fragment navigation state with backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to wrap my head around state and navigation with Fragments in an Activity but I'm stumped while trying to retain the state of my navigation properly. Say I have this kind of navigation path:

```
Activity
   |
FragA
   |_____________
   |     |      |
FragB  FragC  FragD
         |
       FragE
```

FragA is the initial fragment that is displayed when Activity is created. From FragA you can navigate to FragB/FragC/FragD. From FragC you can navigate to FragE. On each level the fragment is added to the backstack so maybe the path could be for example FragA > FragD or FragA > FragC > FragE.

I'm using this code to set the first fragment:

```
private fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit()
}
```

And this code to set the next fragments:

```
fun pushFragment(fragment: Fragment)
    fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
}
```

In order to handle when the activity is restarted, I'm using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to save the current position of the fragment.

In my `onCreate` I basically do this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayFragment(FragA)
        }
    }

private fun displayFragment(page: String) {
        currentFragment = page
        when (page) {
            FRAG_A -> setFragment(FragA())
            FRAG_B -> pushFragment(FragB())
            FRAG_C -> pushFragment(FragC())
            FRAG_D -> pushFragment(FragD())
            FRAG_E -> pushFragment(FragE())
        }
    }
```

Now everything works when I'm currently, for example, on FragC. I restarted the activity and when it's recreated I'm back on FragC as intended, but as soon as I try to navigate to FragE, I'm hit with an `IllegalStateException`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

So after the Activity is recreated, if I'm trying to `commit()` on a fragment transaction it crashed with that Exception. Why? My understanding is the state is already saved when `onSaveInstanceState` is called before the activity restarts, so why is committing transaction after the activity is recreated illegal?

I've read that some solutions use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` in place of `commit()` but I don't quite understand the effects of using it instead of the other.

When I use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` and print the logs I got this:

```
E/Debug: OnCreate Activity
E/Debug: Set fragment: FragA
E/Debug: Push fragment: FragC

<Restarting the activity>

E/Debug: onSaveInstanceState called
E/Debug: OnCreate Activity
E/Debug: onRestoreInstanceState called

<Navigating to FragE>

E/Debug: Push fragment: Frag E
E/Debug: Push fragment: Frag E
```

What's going on there? The log shows as if my fragment transaction for setting FragE is called twice, but when I navigate back and forth on the app the backstack doesn't seem to have any problem, but every time I pushed a new fragment the log would print twice.

Is this the right way to handle navigation with fragments?

Comment: Show body of method displayFragment. When you show fragmentC?

Comment: @CôngHải I've edited the methods to include the name. `displayFragment` only calls `setFragment` for FragA and `pushFragment` for the other fragments. And like I've already said in my question FragC is navigated from FragA. The hierarchy I included refers to the available navigation path from each Fragment.

Comment: What if rotate 2 times?

Comment: "In order to handle when the activity is restarted, I'm using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save the current position of the fragment". It is not needed. `FragmentManager` saves fragments chain itself. You should only check `if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayFragment(FragA)
        }` as you already do.

Comment: You can save any variables in `onSaveInstanceState` and get their values in `onCreate` after rotation.

Comment: @CoolMind yes, that's what I did but I was getting `IllegalStateException` when `commit()` is called. I've already written that I can get it to work by using `commitAllowingStateLoss()`, but the implications are lost on me. Also when I called `pushFragment()` the log is printed twice if I'm using `commitAllowingStateLoss()`

Comment: Could you write some ativity code? For instance, `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`?

Comment: You know, I faced a situation, that after rotating activity fragments in BackStack begin recreate (from zero, not form `newInstance()`). Read http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2015/08/16/how-to-avoid-fragments-overlapping-due-to-backstack-nightmare-in-android/ and understood that fragments in backstack really recteate. I don't know a solution.